# Sheets & Appscripts Hubspot POST Request with Authentication Token Problem

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, hubspot

I've created a GAS app to provide better pipeline reporting from our Hubspot instance. So far the app works and I have successfully created a Sales Pipeline that shows up in Google sheets. I am trying to add a capability that requires a POST method to query Hubspot's CRM V3. I got it to work in Postman but cannot replicate it in GAS.

The error I get is "Authentication credentials not found." The headers print to the log so I assume they are being generated properly. My guess is that my access Token and payload are not being passed properly to the API during the request. Any help on the matter would be much appreciated.

```js
function getConversions() {

  // Prepare authentication to Hubspot
  var service = getService();
  var headers = {headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()}};
  Logger.log(headers);
    

var raw = JSON.stringify({"filterGroups":[{"filters":[{"propertyName":"hs_analytics_last_visit_timestamp","operator":"GT","value":"1561514165666"}]}],"limit":100,"after":0});  
  
var options = {
  'method' : 'post',
  headers: headers,
  'contentType': 'application/json',
  // Convert the JavaScript object to a JSON string.
  body : raw,
  redirect: 'follow',
  "muteHttpExceptions": true
};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/objects/contacts/search?', options);
var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
    Logger.log(result);

 
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- When I checked [the official document of Search of HubSpot API](https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/api/crm/search), I found the curl sample. When this sample is converted to Google Apps Script, I noticed several modification points in your script.

  - `UrlFetchApp.fetch` has no properties of `body` and `redirect`.
  - About `followRedirects`, the official document says as follows.

    > If false the fetch doesn't automatically follow HTTP redirects; it returns the original HTTP response. The default is true.
- In your URL, `https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/objects/contacts/search?` is used. If you don't use the API key, how about modifying to `https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/objects/contacts/search`?

When above modification is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please modify as follows.

From:

```
var options = {
  'method' : 'post',
  headers: headers,
  'contentType': 'application/json',
  // Convert the JavaScript object to a JSON string.
  body : raw,
  redirect: 'follow',
  "muteHttpExceptions": true
};
```

To:

```
var options = {
  method : 'post',
  headers: headers,
  contentType: 'application/json',
  payload : raw,
  muteHttpExceptions: true
};
```

#### Note:

- Above modification is required for your script. But I'm worry about the error of `Authentication credentials not found.`. In this modification, it supposes that your access token of `service.getAccessToken()` can be used for this request. When I saw the official document, the API key can be also used. If the access token cannot be used, how about using the API key? It's like below.

  - `https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/objects/contacts/search?hapikey=YOUR_HUBSPOT_API_KEY`

#### References:

- [Search of HubSpot API](https://developers.hubspot.com/docs/api/crm/search)
- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: Hey Tanaike, I really appreciate that you tried to take a crack at this as this problem has been stumping me for quite a while. I took your advice and changed part of the JSON package along with the endpoint. This approach didn't work but the error changed and indicated that Hubspot didn't like the search parameters which exist in the raw variable. So your advice helped me get through to the API. Your post also made me think about the API key versus token which most of my app uses. So I changed the the URL to include the API key and wallah! It works. The final code below.

Comment: @David Slavich Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function getConversions() {

  // Prepare authentication to Hubspot
  var service = getService();
  var headers = {headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + service.getAccessToken()}};
  var url = 'https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/objects/contacts/search'
  //Logger.log(headers);
    

var raw = {"filterGroups":[{"filters":[{"propertyName":"hs_analytics_last_visit_timestamp","operator":"GT","value":"1561514165666"}]}],"limit":100,"after":0};  
  
var options = {
  method : 'post',
  contentType: "application/json",
  // Convert the JavaScript object to a JSON string.
  payload : JSON.stringify(raw),
  muteHttpExceptions: true
};
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.hubapi.com/crm/v3/objects/contacts/search?hapikey=myapikey',options);
var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  Logger.log(response)  
  Logger.log(result);


};
```